# How to log/trace data export in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to log/trace data exports in SQL Server?
I'm trying to demo that our environment is safe and everything is logged. But when I try to trace (standard template) the data export it doesn't really show in the trace. I can see the query but nothing really shows that the data was exported.

We don't have a dedicated DBA yet so this kind of fell on me.

Comment: What do you mean "data export". SSIS has its own logs. An external application just reads the data. In any case, have you enabled auditing? Or are you simply looking at the logs?

Comment: I mean when in SQL management studio you right-click a database  - Tasks - Export data (wizard). How is that action logged and where can I found it?